# iOS memory leak in NSSortDescriptor code

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, nsarray, nsentitydescription

I am getting a memory leak (see >> below) in the following CLASS helper function.

```
    + (NSArray *)findAllRoomsInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [self entityDescriptionInContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    >> NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]; 
    >> NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]; 
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        //handle errors
    }

    sortDescriptors = nil;

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you alloc the `sortDescriptor` and `sortDescriptors` but not release them at end

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease]; 
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
```

Comment: Using ARC so it will not compile if I release.

Comment: are you sure you are using ARC? because there is a `autorelease` in your code

Comment: Guess I am excluding that file from ARC during compile. Thx.